# Refresh Page On Back Button in Browser using jquery or php

Tags: javascript

Hello Friends I am Using These Code To Refresh page On Click Browser Back Button..These Code Work With Opera And Chrome but Didn't Work With IE 10 And Firefox...

```
<input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">

<script type="text/javascript">
  onload=function(){
    var e=document.getElementById("refreshed");
    if(e.value=="no")e.value="yes";
    else{e.value="no";location.reload();}
  }
</script>
```

Please Friends Help Me And Please Don't Mark It As Duplicate Instead Of Helping..If You Have Another Code So Please Provide Me...And Thanx In Advance

Comment: use this : window.location.reload(true); insted of location.reload();

Comment: window.location.reload() or 
location['reload']()

Comment: Thanks Soren For your comment but this code also not working....i think IE10 and firefox using the history for back button instead of loading page...if you have sollution for history so please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
location.reload(forcedReload);
```

should work for all browsers.